# How is PTX compressed in a fatbinary?

Tags: decompress

It is not clear how PTX is compressed in a fatbinary. I'm doing some research and by looking at the binary it seems a sort of LZ77 (or LZSS?).
I've prepared some tests:

Small PTX. A simple vec_add (poorly implemented): [Input](https://pastebin.com/QF95YiAN),[Output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ouv2sXyYqm6TPg67ZMeN456EP9eFaNd4/view?usp=sharing) and [CUDA Source](https://pastebin.com/k4zU09sa).

Larger PTX. lavaMD from Rodinia Benchmarks: [Input](https://pastebin.com/BDb9wxdz), [Output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c7yLuwcFITZKpwLbKQJh-90FdLgPLWkd/view?usp=sharing) and [CUDA Source](https://pastebin.com/TasYV3bf)

Note: The question is the same of the following thread on
[NVIDIA Developers Forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1042870/ptx-compression-method) (I am the author of the thread).

Comment: Is your question, "How is PTX encoded in a fatbinary?" It is best to clearly ask your question when posting so that those responding know what to answer.

Comment: @dingo_kinznerhook Done. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: "I'm doing some research and by looking at the binary it seems a sort of LZ77 compression." Which binary are you looking at? `vec_add.fatbin` is clearly not compressed.

Comment: @SYS_V The binary is not compressed, but the PTX code inside yes. The PTX code is saved as a string inside the fatbin. You can try to download the second link a open it with a text editor. You can see pieces of strings regarding the PTX, but it is not in a plaintext form.

Comment: encoding != compression.  Are you able to provide larger samples (on the order of kilobytes or megabytes in size)? The tiny amount of data in the file provided is insufficient for meaningful analysis.

Comment: @SYS_V I've updated a larger example. I can try to cook a bigger one. I think that PTX maximum size is 2MB

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is rather old, but I recently also needed to understand the compression of CUDA fatbinaries. It indeed seems to be a compression somewhat similar to LZ77. I wrote the following code that seems to decompress the actual text sections of compressed fatbinaries.

```
size_t decompress(const uint8_t* input, size_t input_size, uint8_t* output, size_t output_size)
{
    size_t ipos = 0, opos = 0;  
    uint16_t next_nclen;  // length of next non-compressed segment
    uint16_t next_clen;   // length of next compressed segment
    uint16_t back_offset; // negative offset where redudant data is located, relative to current opos

    while (ipos < input_size) {
        next_nclen = (input[ipos] & 0xf0) >> 4;
        next_clen = 4 + (input[ipos] & 0xf);
        if (next_nclen == 0xf) {
            next_nclen += input[++ipos];
        }
        
        if (memcpy(output + opos, input + (++ipos), next_nclen) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error copying data");
            return 0;
        }
        ipos += next_nclen;
        opos += next_nclen;
        if (ipos >= input_size || opos >= output_size) {
            break;
        }
        back_offset = input[ipos] + (input[ipos + 1] << 8);       
        ipos += 2;
        if (next_clen == 0xf+4) {
            do {
                next_clen += input[ipos++];
            } while (input[ipos - 1] == 0xff);
        }
        if (next_clen <= back_offset) {
            if (memcpy(output + opos, output + opos - back_offset, next_clen) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error copying data");
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            if (memcpy(output + opos, output + opos - back_offset, back_offset) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error copying data");
                return 0;
            }
            for (size_t i = back_offset; i < next_clen; i++) {
                output[opos + i] = output[opos + i - back_offset];
            }
        }
        opos += next_clen;
    }
    return opos;
}
```

I am no compression expert but I think this is a variant of LZ4 compression. There is some more code related to decoding the fatbinary headers here: https://github.com/n-eiling/cuda-fatbin-decompression.
The output is bit identical to using nvcc with the `--no-compress` flag.